# Explicit reference to actionscript class in top level package

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, asc2

If you define a class in actionscript that has the same name as a class in the top level package (e.g. Array) there seems to be no way of explicitly referencing the class in the top level package.

UPDATE: This issue is only appearing in Flash Builder 4.7 with the new ASC 2.0 compiler, using Flash Builder 4.6 with an 'old' Flex SDK it works.

Example:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import mypackage.Array;

    public class AS3Problem extends Sprite
    {
        public function AS3Problem()
        {

            var myOwnArray:mypackage.Array = new mypackage.Array(); 
            // The line below will cause a compile error 
            // 'Ambiguous reference to Array'
            var flashArray:Array = new Array(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I know the simple solution to this problem is to not create classes with a name that is the same as an as3 top level package class/function, but I'm intrigued as to how this could be 'fixed' in some way by explicitly referring to this package or some other means.

For those interested, I happened to accidentally import 'Array' from hamcrest-as3 while writing tests which caused a problem like this.

Comment: I edited my answer(I am not sure  if you get notifications for edits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this line

```
 import mypackage.Array;
```

so you do not import this custom Array and you always use the fully qualified name, I did not tested it but this should fix it.

EDIT:
I tested this and yes you have to add this import line, it will not work , but I can't reproduce the error, I can use and custom Array and the global Array fine  with no issue/error or warrning.

EDIT2:
This also worked for me, can you test this too?

```
var globalArray:Class=(getDefinitionByName('Array') as Class);
var arr2:*=new globalArray();
arr2.push("test");
trace(arr2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work. I've tried it and that change will give me another error: "Access of possibly undefined property mypackage." (I think this would work in java, but AS3 behaves differently and requires you to import classes even if you explicitly name them in your code)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? (I'm testing this in flash builder 4.7 using the AIR 4.0 Beta SDK)

Comment: I am using FB4.6 with the AIR 3.y SDK(I am not 100% sure of the version )

Comment: I checked with 4.6 and Flex SDK 4.6.0 - in that case it works, so this isssue has probably been introduced in either Flash Builder 4.7 or in the ASC 2.0 compiler (http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/actionscript-compiler-backward-compatibility.html)